# How to get through facebook review process with ios app only in testflight?

Tags: facebook

I have an app where I am pulling events from different APIs among other the facebook API. For now I am just pulling the facebook events for testers. However, in order to get access to pulling facebook events from all users I need to get the app through the review process for user_events.

My problem is that my app is still in development mode and I cannot release it to the app-store before I have gotten the access from Facebook. But as I understand it, facebook have to review the app themselves. I do not understand how I can possibly get the app through review when they cannot download it - at least I would have to know their emailadresse in order to send an invitation through testflight.

Would it be fine just do create a video of how it looks without facebook getting access to the app or what would be the appropriate approach?

Comment: This isn't a programming question, this is a customer support question that only Facebook can answer.

Comment: @Lexi I get your point. However, I am asking this question here since facebook's documentation does not seem to answer this and it could be that others had been in a similar situation.

Comment: This type of question gets closed often because it's not a programming question. You will need to contact Facebook to see how they want to handle it.